# implementing smtp in sailsjs, for masked emails

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, sails.js

For a while I've wanted to create my own email server that can create disposable emails to mask my own, and also use my own server rather than gmail.

I first figured id should create a nodejs server (server A) that handles all the incomming mail, and save the mail to a database, and then let another server (server B) know a email was recieved and let the corresponding user know "hey, you got mail!".

Server B would be the one based on sailsjs and users could login, access mail and settings. Where as server A will only be a nodejs server with minimum code. No interface or anything.

However, this seemed messy, connecting between servers.

I started thinking about combining sailsjs and smtp-server to create what i want. But can I really run smtp-server and sailsjs combined?

Can I go something as (example):
    var SMTPServer = require('smtp-server');
    var server = new SMTPServer(options);
    server.listen(sailsjs); //instance of sailsjs server

**In short:**
combine smtp-server and sailsjs to handle incomming mail. Sending alert to users using socket.io. And letting users log into a dashboard to administrate their mail settings. 
Whats the best way to handle this?

I'm going to create a github project on this if anyone gets curius on progress:
https://github.com/sciencefyll/sailsjs-email-server

But be warned, I'm not sure how to deal with this ...

npm modules:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/smtp-server
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Successfully added an smtp server to sailsjs using hooks in api/hooks. simply set the port and run the server in initialize() and you're good to go!

Look in my github for working and ongoing code.
https://github.com/sciencefyll/sailsjs-email-server

here's also what you need to know to create your own hook:
http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/Hooks